# I am trying to install eHDPrep on openSUSE Leap 15.5 but its giving me errors

Tags: r-package

I am using openSUSE Leap 15.5 and trying to install eHDPrep, an R package for data quality.

I am using R version R-base-4.2.2-bp155.5.57.x86_64 and I installed these dependencies first found on https://github.com/overton-group/eHDPrep/ and used install.packages("eHDPrep") to install the package.

I got the results below but the package doesn't load;

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpQAhovF/downloaded_packages’
There were 39 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there were some dependencies that had to be installed on OpenSUSE first. I installed the dependency below using the Konsole. You can use Yast to install it as well.

sudo zypper install gcc-fortran